# How to create regex to match "String""" as two strings

Tags: java, regex, lexer, jflex

I need to match "String""" as two strings.

I'm using this for my school project (Lexer implementation) and I'm having a problem with situation when I get something like **"Something"""** being matched as one string **Something""**

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
"(.*?)"
```

where `*?` is the lazy 0 or more token.

Comment: Actually it gives me an error because it does not match **""**

Comment: Works for me. How are you using it? I am using `Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"")` and then getting the matcher `pattern.matcher("\"Something\"\"\"")`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this too and it did work with every online tester I found but in Java flex file it just didn't do what it is supposed to.

I found a way to solve this:


`<YYINITIAL> \"      {yybegin(STRING); string.setLength(0); }

<STRING> {

   \"   {yybegin(YYINITIAL); return new_symbol(sym.STRING, string.toString()); }

     {StringCharacter} + { string.append( yytext() ); }

}`